# using R data.table to look up cumulative stock return values over a range of 15 months

Tags: r, data.table, stock

I am trying to calculate 15-months stock returns for a set of U.S. companies. I always used SAS for this, but my SAS licence expired.

The data looks as follows, where I added 1 to the monthly returns

Return data (crsp.msf), the source data:

```
permno date      ret
10002 1994-01-31 1.039
10002 1994-02-28 0.991
10002 1994-03-31 1.005
10002 1994-04-29 0.943
10002 1994-05-31 1.060
10002 1994-06-30 1.061
10002 1994-07-29 0.946
10002 1994-08-31 1.009
10002 1994-09-30 0.977
10002 1994-10-31 1.000
10002 1994-11-30 0.962
10002 1994-12-30 1.056
10002 1995-01-31 1.000
10002 1995-02-28 1.000
10002 1995-03-31 0.978
10002 1995-04-28 1.020
10002 1995-05-31 1.038
10002 1995-06-30 0.969
10002 1995-07-31 1.000
10002 1995-08-31 1.000
10002 1995-09-29 1.122
10002 1995-10-31 0.862
10002 1995-11-30 1.070
10002 1995-12-29 1.053
```

For this firm 10002, for each month, I want to find the returns over 15 months, as specified in the list (elist) below:

```
permno,begdat,enddat
10002,1994-03-31,1995-06-30
10002,1994-06-30,1995-09-30
10002,1994-09-30,1995-12-31
10002,1994-12-31,1996-03-31
10002,1995-03-31,1996-06-30
10002,1995-06-30,1996-09-30
10002,1995-09-30,1996-12-31
10002,1995-12-31,1997-03-31
```

I have a long list of firms, so 'elist' has 40000 rows.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your data is already in datatables, you could use the `foverlaps` function for this:

```
# create a begindate ('bdat') and enddate ('edat') from the 'date' column
crsp.mrf[, `:=` (bdat = as.Date(date), edat = as.Date(date))][, date := NULL]
# convert the date columns in 'elist to Date format (only if they aren't already)
elist[, `:=` (begdat = as.Date(begdat), enddat = as.Date(enddat))]

# set the keys
setkey(crsp.mrf, permno, bdat, edat)
setkey(elist, permno, begdat, enddat)

# see which dates fall in the specified date-windows from 'elist' and calculate the sum for each window
foverlaps(crsp.mrf, elist, type = "within", nomatch=0L)[, .(sum.ret = sum(ret)), by = .(permno, begdat, enddat)]
```

which gives:

```
   permno     begdat     enddat sum.ret
1:  10002 1994-03-31 1995-06-30  16.024
2:  10002 1994-06-30 1995-09-30  16.138
3:  10002 1994-09-30 1995-12-31  16.107
4:  10002 1994-12-31 1996-03-31  12.112
5:  10002 1995-03-31 1996-06-30  10.112
6:  10002 1995-06-30 1996-09-30   7.076
7:  10002 1995-09-30 1996-12-31   2.985
```

Comment: I liked your answer here, you are really good at text mining !!!!!! or string managing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using `data.table`.

```
dt[date %between% c("1994-03-31","1995-06-30")]
```

Result.

```
    permno       date   ret
 1:  10002 1994-03-31 1.005
 2:  10002 1994-04-29 0.943
 3:  10002 1994-05-31 1.060
 4:  10002 1994-06-30 1.061
 5:  10002 1994-07-29 0.946
 6:  10002 1994-08-31 1.009
 7:  10002 1994-09-30 0.977
 8:  10002 1994-10-31 1.000
 9:  10002 1994-11-30 0.962
10:  10002 1994-12-30 1.056
11:  10002 1995-01-31 1.000
12:  10002 1995-02-28 1.000
13:  10002 1995-03-31 0.978
14:  10002 1995-04-28 1.020
15:  10002 1995-05-31 1.038
16:  10002 1995-06-30 0.969
```

If you want to do this for the entire elist, you can do the following. First read your data using `read.table`.

```
elist <- read.table(text="
permno,begdat,enddat
10002,1994-03-31,1995-06-30
10002,1994-06-30,1995-09-30
10002,1994-09-30,1995-12-31
10002,1994-12-31,1996-03-31
10002,1995-03-31,1996-06-30
10002,1995-06-30,1996-09-30
10002,1995-09-30,1996-12-31
10002,1995-12-31,1997-03-31", header=T, sep = ",", fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then use a simple `for loop`.

```
res <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(elist)){
  res <- rbind(res, dt[date %between% c(elist[i,2],elist[i,3])])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks helpers! The MySql solution for the questions would be: `create table return1 as select a.*, b.ret, b.date from elist as a, crsp.msf as b where a.permno = b.permno and (b.date > a.begdat and b.date <= a.enddat)`

However, this took 2 hours (!) to produce the desired result.

**Using data.table**

First, define a function, where `ri` is `crsp.msf`, and `row` the row number in `elist`:

```
cumret <- function(ri,row){
    r<-ri[permno==elist[row,permno],]
    r<-r[date>elist[row,begdat] & date<=elist[row,enddat],.(ret)]
    r<-r[,.(prod(ret,na.rm = FALSE)-1)]
    return(r)
}
```

Note that I use two steps to retrieve the relevant observations from `ri`. I could do it in 1 step, but that takes too much time. The penultimate row of the function calculates the cumulative returns.

Second, add a `returns` column to `elist`:

`elist[, return := NA_real_]`

Lastly, loop through elist:

`for (row in 1:elist[,.N]){
    elist[row,return:=cumret(ri,row)]
}`

This took about 2 minutes for 40k of observations.